# An introduction to control systems

Tags: reference-request, control-theory

I am looking for an introduction on control systems in the context of engineering, but treated from a more mathematical point of view. Does anybody have a good reference?

Comment: Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction by Donald Kirk is a good way to go.  So is Khalil's Nonlinear Systems.

Comment: Though I should point out that there are several schools of Control theory, each with their own mathematical backgrounds that are necessary.

Comment: @Joel Thanks :) Mathematical background shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: *Modern Control Engineering,Katsuhiko Ogata* if you want "much" mathematics.

Comment: @K.Rmth Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to peruse these online.

Linear Control(mostly):

- Modern Control Theory (3rd Edition), William L. Brogan
- Mathematical Control Theory: Deterministic Finite Dimensional Systems. Eduardo D. Sontag, Second Edition, Springer, New York, 1998 (you can review entire book online)

**Update**

Nonlinear Control:

- Nonlinear Optimal Control Theory, L. D. Berkovitz, N. G. Medhin
- Nonlinear Control Systems II, (v. 2), Alberto Isidori

Comment: Thanks! :) I'd like to take a look at both, I think. Any advice?

Comment: Oh, nice! I found the second one online!

Comment: :) It also look very, very well written. Do you know if there are solutions of the exercises around? I'm working the first couple, but while one was easy, on another one I had to compute a quite big differential equation, and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution...

Comment: I added two nonlinear ones, you can also peruse online. Good luck! Regards

Answer (score 2):

[Feedback systems: An introduction to scientists and engineers](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/Main_Page) is an excellent book and is available for free. The site also contains lot of supplemental material.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like a very useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

For linear control systems, "Linear System Theory" by Wilson Rugh offers a pretty good treatment of things. For nonlinear systems, I like "Nonlinear Systems" by Hassan Khalil because it covers certain aspects of nonlinear dynamical systems such as bifurcations, limit cycles, and other features not found in linear systems in addition to discussing various techniques of how control of nonlinear systems.

For optimal control, Daniel Liberzon has a book called "Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory" which has a preliminary version available [here](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc.pdf) for free. In it, he builds the important tools of optimal control theory from the ground up in a clear and concise way. The book also proves Pontryagin's Maximum Principle (which is among the most important results in optimal control and not proven in every book) and later he covers a few more advanced topics such as hybrid systems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at those (in particular the online version of the book).